# How do I use grep to find a text string in files in sub folders of a parent folder without -r switch

Tags: grep, solaris, recursive, posix

I'm using Solaris 10 and have two `grep` versions one in `/usr/bin` and one in `/usr/xpg4/bin`. I have been searching for an answer on how to search for text within files within sub folders of a parent directory using `grep`. All answers talk about `-r` or `-R` switches which I do not have available with my version of `grep`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard (POSIX) syntax is:

```
find /path/to/parent -type f -exec grep 'XXX' /dev/null {} +
```

(the `/dev/null` is to make sure `grep` always prints a file name). That will work on all POSIX systems including Solaris. The only known post-90s systems where that's known not to work is old (very old now) GNU systems.

GNU initially introduced a `-print0` predicate and a `-0` option to `xargs` instead for that:

```
find /path/to/parent -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'XXX' /dev/null
```

There are now a few other implementations that support that, but not Solaris.

<sub>Above, in theory, you'd want to add `-r` option to avoid running `grep` if there's not file, but that's not as *portable* and in this particular case, doesn't make a functional difference</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Using GNU `grep` (if installed):

```
ggrep -A3 -B23 'word' -R /log/
```

This will check every files in folder if the regular expression `word` is matched and will show output together with file path.

GNU `grep` supports the `-R` flag.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use ggrep which on solaris exists on `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep` path like this:
`/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -H 'search-term' <file-name>*`
it searches your search term on a group of file names starting with a specific word.